# C# Variable int assumes a different value

Tags: c#, variables, input

I'm trying to create a simple program to calculate an average. The user should enter a positive number, then I create a loop to sum from 0 to the number entered. Then the average is the total divided by the number entered.

Problem: When I enter a number, for example, 10, the variable becomes 58. To any value that I enter, it always adds 48. Anyone have a clue about this issue?

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace inClass1
{
    class Loops
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int total = 0;
            int num;
            Console.Write("Enter a positive number: ");

            num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

            for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
            {
                total = total + i;
            }

            double average = total / (double)num;
            Console.WriteLine("The average is = " + average);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A good opportunity to learn about [ASCII codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), something every programmer should know.

Comment: This would make a great interview question...

Comment: @HansPassant I respectfully disagree. I don't think many programmers need to know about ASCII. But almost all need to know about [Unicode](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF).

Answer (score 5):

It's because `Console.Read` method reads the first `char` and returns its `ASCII` value. And it only reads *one* char, so you can't read more than one number at the same time. To fix that just use `Console.ReadLine` to take a `string` as input:

```
 um = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

In case where the user inputs an invalid number this will fail. To prevent that you can look into [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Thank you @Selman22, it worked! I'll take a look on the int.Parse method!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `Console.Read`.

That method returns a `int`, not a `string`. That int is the Unicode character code of the read character. The overload of `Convert.ToInt32` that takes a int looks like this:

```
public static int ToInt32(int value) {
        return value;
    }
```

[(Reference Source)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,ac1a3422e6436d68)

Which means that its just returning the passed value (instead of parsing). Unicode '1' is the number 49.

Instead, use `Console.ReadLine` which in addition to getting the whole input (not just the first character) will return a string, so that `int.Parse` is called on it instead of casting when you use `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: @Selman22 Wow, thats what I get for not *carefully* reading the docs. Fixed.

Comment: Not ASCII; Unicode (after being translated per Console.InputEncoding).

Comment: @TomBlodget Interesting, they are the same in this case. Thanks for the clarification